# What is the meaning of alphanumerics in Java expression

Tags: java

Please explain with a little detail what is the meaning of alphanumerics behind the equal sign of these expressions:

```
public static final int InfoMuslim=0x7f0701a9;
public static final int InfoMuslimUrl=0x7f0701aa;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Above alphanumeric in JAVA Expression is `HexaDeciamal` numbers :

Java Hexadecimal Numbering System

Definition:

Java **hexadecimal** is a numbering system with a base of 16.

It uses all the numerals 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 as well as the letters A,B,C,D,E,F for each digit of a number.

In a similar way that the Italian language represents the English word 'number' as 'numero', hexadecimal represents the denary number of 122 as 7A.

Java hexadecimal (or ‘hex’ for short) is just another system to represent the same value.

To show the progression of the hexadecimal numbering system, look at the hexadecimal values below as they are converted from denary numbers. The hex system has a radix, or base, of 16. Note that once it gets to ten, the l system uses letters:

**Denary=Hexadecimal**

0=0;1=1;2=2;3=3;4=4;5=5;6=6;7=7;8=8;9=9;10=A;11=B;12=C;13=D;14=E;15=F and so on.

**Hexadecimal=Binary**

0=0000;1=0001;2=0010;3=0011;4=0100,5=0101;6=0110;7=0111;

8=1000;9=1001;A=1010;B=1011;C=1100;D=1101;E=1110; F=1111

So, (E)16 in hex is equal to (1110)2 in binary.

For more information refer below link :

http://java.about.com/od/h/g/hexadecimal.htm

Thanks..!!

Comment: @Escada Jakarta : Welcome..!!

Answer (score 2):

These are [hexadecimal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal). So, e.g. `0x7f0701a9` means `7f0701a9` hex number, which is the same as `2131165609` decimal number.

You can experiment with them using [any online converter](http://www.binaryhexconverter.com/hex-to-decimal-converter) or Windows Calculator app.

Comment: And for the official source: [Java Language Specification 3.10.1. Integer Literals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1-400)